# Including php in a html5 code

Tags: php, html, include

I've a php code that I want to include in my html5 code. The php code looks like this:

```
<?php
$accounts = mysql_connect("localhost","root","tungdesign") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("database", $accounts);

$sql ="SELECT * FROM users";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $accounts);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$username=$row['Username'];
$first=$row['Firstnam'];    

 echo $username . "'s first name is ". $first . "<br>";
}

?>
```

This code I been trying to include in my html5 code using the include command, so in the body of the html doc I've added this:

```
<?php include("About.php");?>
```

When I just open the php file it works, but included in the html5 file, I can't see the output. Is it because of the echo in php or why can't it be displayed in the website?

First time I've asked a question here and I hope you guys can give me an answer. Also I been trying to search for an answer for a couple of hours, so this is my last hope.

Comment: is this html file a `.html` file? or `.php`? .html is generally NOT parsed by the php interpreter in the webserver, and any php code in it will NEVER be executed.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: The html file is .html @Marc B. Thanks, I'll look into that! Shivan Raptor

Answer (score 3):

when you say HTML5 code - what do you mean? because PHP needs to be executed with .php files.

if your invoking HTML5 is a .html - it wont execute.

what you need to do is use html5 inside php

so 
index.php should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <?php
 include('About.php');
 ?>
</html>
```

but index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <?php
 include('About.php');
 ?>
</html>
```

wont yield anything because the  .html wont understand what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t matter what else is in the file. PHP just treats it as text to be output until it sees a `<?php`.

If the code isn’t executing then your server isn’t processing the file for PHP directives.

The most likely causes for this are:

- You aren’t loading it through a web server.
- You haven’t installed PHP.
- You have given the file a `.html` extension but not changed the server configuration to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can put HTML in PHP – not the other way. I mean – if your server doesn’t parse `.htm` files with PHP parser (you need to change server settings to do that) – it will be just HTML and therefore PHP embedded in its code will not work.